Using NodeJS Local Server vs Wildfly Server
I know that NodeJS excels at creating local development servers for web applications. There are many NodeJS versions, some of them has reached end of life and some of them has security support. And NodeJS regularly detects vulnerabilities and fixes it for its current versions.
I have many web applications which are written with outdated NodeJS versions in Production Environment, and they are running on Wildfly server. I wonder if web applications written with the outdated NodeJS version and deployed on Wildfly server have vulnerabilities that fixed in the current NodeJS versions? I think If NodeJS just provides local development servers, it shouldn't have vulnerabilities, because I run them on Wildfly server. If not, why outdated NodeJS version affects my web application running on Wildfly server? Why would my web applications running on Wildfly have vulnerabilities from NodeJS? Should I upgrade NodeJS to current version?
Any help would be appreciated.
I researched NodeJS and Wildfly sources but I can't find a sufficient answer.

I try to put it simple: Many years ago, Javascript has been created with the Web in mind. Since then it runs inside Browsers and allows you to manipulate the DOM.
Someone thought that it would be great idea to run Javascript on a regular computer too (outside of a browser) and created NodeJS.
NodeJS is platform for running Javascript code on a computer. NodeJS has access to the file system of the machine that it runs on, and sockets (udp, tcp) and much more. They leveraged it even further and created libraries that can communicate over different protocols, for example HTTP.
Today, you can do just about anything with NodeJS. You can write simple scripts and control your pc or write Web applications. You can connect different physical devices over any protocol that you can imagine or invent new ones. Anything, really.
But people think and work different. So, some people use the NodeJS toolset to create their own 'new' things like Wildfly. Speaking broadly, they use the HTTP Framework of NodeJS and implement new workflows and concepts on top of it.
Using existing tools like NodeJS to create new ones like Wildfly automatically implies that if NodeJS suffers from a bug, then Wildfly will too because they inherit from the very same Request/Response objects of NodeJS, for example. (On top of that Wildfly might introduce their own vulnerabilities too.)
Building your apps and tools means that you will always have dependencies. Borrowing code is cool because nobody wants to re-invent the wheel - although in JS world this is a common illness - but the quality of external packages may vary and by having dependencies (that have dependencies, that have other dependencies, that have...) you enter this long list of... well dependencies. A bug in the beginning of that chain, drags its effects over to every other chain link.
